# given a triangle and a segment, find third point which would create a similar triangle

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, geometry

I've seen similar questions asked, but I find the explanations still somewhat difficult.

I have a triangle with its 3 vertices given in (x,y). I am also given a segment of two points. I want to place a third point around the segment so that it completes a triangle with similar shape to the original triangle. This new triangle might not be the same size, but all the angles would be the same. How would I find this third point?

I have gotten as far as finding the length of each segment and the angles of the triangle, but I'm kind of stuck.

I saw the following post and tried to implement the code discussed with no luck on getting the correct coordinates..
[Calculating the coordinates of the third point of a triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883849/calculating-the-coordinates-of-the-third-point-of-a-triangle)

Edit: Sorry about that, I forgot to specify that I know that I want to place my third point close to one of the ends of the segment. Example: I have triangle with verticies A, B, and C. I have a segment DE (created by points D and E), where DE is similar to AB. I want to place point F at a position so that AD is similar to EF and AC is similar to DF.

Comment: This problem is underspecified.  The segment you are given could make up any of the three sides, so there must be three different points that could be used to make similar triangles.

Comment: This is off topic - should be on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Drew - There are actually six solutions in general, since the segment can be oriented in two directions with respect to each side. But so what? OP just wants some triangle similar to the original that has the segment as one of the sides.

Comment: @Ted, Only three orientations will result in a similar triangle.

Comment: @Ted:  You're right, of course (on both counts).  I just wanted the OP to think about the problem a little more.

Comment: @Draw: ah sorry about that, I just looked over it again and realized that I wasn't specific enough. Please see edit. Thanks!

Comment: For any segments AB and DE, AB is similar to DE (meaning that can be made identical by translation, rotation, and scaling).  This means that you have to have a way of telling whether DE should be treated as equivalent to AB, BC, or CA.

Comment: @David: Yes David, I do have a way of telling what DE should be treated as. That information I do have.

Comment: @Agnel - the standard definition of similar triangles includes mirror images. See, for example, [here](http://www.mathopenref.com/similartriangles.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)).

Comment: @Ted - Thanks. I did not know this. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of being specific, suppose your original triangle has vertices A, B, and C. The line segment has end points D and E. Furthermore, you want DE to correspond to AB. The problem is then to find a point F such that triangle DEF is similar to triangle ABC. I hope that's what you're trying to solve, because that's what I'm going to give you as a solution. Explaining the solution is going to be a lot longer than coding it. :)

I think you can do all this with vector arithmetic, without using angles and trig functions. Let all points be represented by their x and y coordinates in some shared coordinate system. (If you don't know vector arithmetic, see the appendix below.)

First, we'll imagine a local coordinate system u-v with A as the origin and AB parallel to the u axis; the v axis is perpendicular to u; we'll nail down which direction is positive in a second. Now, even though AB is the side of the triangle, from now on we'll think of it as a vector from A to B. It can be computed in the x-y system as `AB = (B[x] - A[x], B[y] - A[y])`. The same goes for all other point pairs. Individual points will also be vectors in the x-y system. A unit vector in the x-y system along the u axis is given by:

```
u = (u_x, u_y) = AB / ‖AB‖
```

A unit vector along the v axis is just:

```
v = (-u_y, u_x)
```

(We could also have used `(u_y, -u_x)`.) We will now compute the vector components of AC in the u-v system:

```
AC_u = (AC_x * u_x, AC_y * u_y) // = (AC ∙ u)
AC_v = ‖AC - AC_u * u‖
```

Now we imagine another local coordinate system, r-s, with origin at D and r axis along DE. The unit vectors along r and s in the x-y system are:

```
r = (r_x, r_y) = DE / ‖DE‖
s = (-r_y, r_x)
```

We can scale the u-v components of AC by the ratio `‖DE‖ / ‖AB‖` to get r-s components of DF:

```
DF_r = AC_u * ‖DE‖ / ‖AB‖
DF_s = AC_v * ‖DE‖ / ‖AB‖
```

Finally, we just need to add everything together:

```
F = D + DF_r * r + DF_s * s
```

(Recall that `D`, `r`, and `s` are vectors.) That's it. Although the post is long, there are only a dozen or so lines of code (each vector calculation step takes one lines for each component) plus another handful for a function to compute the norm of a vector.

---

APPENDIX: Vector arithmetic

Vectors in an x-y coordinate system are ordered pairs of numbers: (x, y). Two vectors A and B can be added or subtracted by adding or subtracting their components: `A ± B = (A_x ± B_x, A_y ± B_y)`. A vector can be multiplied by a number (also called a *scalar*) by multiplying each vector component by the scalar: `q*A = (q*A_x, q*A_y)`. Division by a scalar is just multiplication by the inverse of the scalar. The *norm* of a vector A (also called its length) is written ‖A‖; it can be computed using the Pythagorean theorem: `‖A‖ = sqrt(A_x * A_x + A_y * A_y)`. A *unit vector* is a vector with norm = 1. The *dot product* of two vectors is the sum (a simple number) of the products of corresponding components: `A ∙ B = A_x*B_x + A_y*B_y`. Note that the dot product of a vector with itself is the square of its norm. An important identity about the dot product is: `A ∙ B = ‖A‖ * ‖B‖ * cos(α)` where `α` is the angle between A and B. A corollary is that the dot product of two non-zero vectors is zero exactly when the vectors are perpendicular to one another.